# Is there a way to take the first 1000 rows of a Spark Dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using the `randomSplit`function to get a small amount of a dataframe to use in dev purposes and I end up just taking the first df that is returned by this function.

```
val df_subset = data.randomSplit(Array(0.00000001, 0.01), seed = 12345)(0)
```

If I use `df.take(1000)` then I end up with an array of rows- not a dataframe, so that won't work for me.

Is there a better, simpler way to take say the first 1000 rows of the df and store it as another df?

Answer (score 213, accepted):

The method you are looking for is [.limit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#limit(n:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BT%5D).

> Returns a new Dataset by taking the first n rows. The difference between this function and head is that head returns an array while limit returns a new Dataset.

Example usage:

```
df.limit(1000)
```

Comment: Just for the record, I used .limit and it returned a Dataset instead of DataFrame (which was not a problem)

Comment: Thanks for the update. It seems that Spark 2.X has changed quite a bit :)