# Take n rows from a spark dataframe and pass to toPandas()

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql

I have this code:

```
l = [('Alice', 1),('Jim',2),('Sandra',3)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(l, ['name', 'age'])
df.withColumn('age2', df.age + 2).toPandas()
```

Works fine, does what it needs to. Suppose though I only want to display the first n rows, and then call `toPandas()` to return a pandas dataframe. How do I do it? I can't call `take(n)` because that doesn't return a dataframe and thus I can't pass it to `toPandas()`.

So to put it another way, how can I take the top n rows from a dataframe and call `toPandas()` on the resulting dataframe? Can't think this is difficult but I can't figure it out.

I'm using Spark 1.6.0.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You can use the `limit(n)` function:

```
l = [('Alice', 1),('Jim',2),('Sandra',3)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(l, ['name', 'age'])
df.limit(2).withColumn('age2', df.age + 2).toPandas()
```

Or:

```
l = [('Alice', 1),('Jim',2),('Sandra',3)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(l, ['name', 'age'])
df.withColumn('age2', df.age + 2).limit(2).toPandas()
```

Comment: It is not safe to assume rerunning data frame.limit(2) will always return the same result(it's not deterministic). I tried this and got stuck in hours of debugging.

Comment: @KaranSharma does that mean when we use limit(n) we are randomly selecting n rows instead of returning top n rows?

Comment: @haneulkim Yes, you are right. Limit randomly selects the rows it wants to.

Answer (score 18):

You could get first rows of Spark DataFrame with [head](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.head) and then create Pandas DataFrame:

```
l = [('Alice', 1),('Jim',2),('Sandra',3)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(l, ['name', 'age'])

df_pandas = pd.DataFrame(df.head(3), columns=df.columns)

In [4]: df_pandas
Out[4]: 
     name  age
0   Alice    1
1     Jim    2
2  Sandra    3
```

Comment: is there a significant difference between `head()` and `limit()`?

Comment: @jamiet `head` return first n rows like `take`, and [`limit`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.limit) limits resulted Spark Dataframe to a specified number. Probably in that case `limit` is more appropriate.

Comment: [difference between `limit` and `head`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34206635/4542359)

Comment: ah, easy. So `limit()` is a transformation, `head()` is an action. Thanks Anton.

Answer (score -5):

Try it:

```py
def showDf(df, count=None, percent=None, maxColumns=0):
    if (df == None): return
    import pandas
    from IPython.display import display
    pandas.set_option('display.encoding', 'UTF-8')
    # Pandas dataframe
    dfp = None
    # maxColumns param
    if (maxColumns >= 0):
        if (maxColumns == 0): maxColumns = len(df.columns)
        pandas.set_option('display.max_columns', maxColumns)
    # count param
    if (count == None and percent == None): count = 10 # Default count
    if (count != None):
        count = int(count)
        if (count == 0): count = df.count()
        pandas.set_option('display.max_rows', count)
        dfp = pandas.DataFrame(df.head(count), columns=df.columns)
        display(dfp)
    # percent param
    elif (percent != None):
        percent = float(percent)
        if (percent >=0.0 and percent <= 1.0):
            import datetime
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            seed = long(now.strftime("%H%M%S"))
            dfs = df.sample(False, percent, seed)
            count = df.count()
            pandas.set_option('display.max_rows', count)
            dfp = dfs.toPandas()    
            display(dfp)
```

Examples of usages are:

```py
# Shows the ten first rows of the Spark dataframe
showDf(df)
showDf(df, 10)
showDf(df, count=10)

# Shows a random sample which represents 15% of the Spark dataframe
showDf(df, percent=0.15)
```