# Write first 5 rows into hdfs file through spark

Tags: apache-spark

I want to write first 5 lines to a hdfs file through spark code

```
sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/hadoop/data-master/retail_db/products/part-00000").map( rec => ( rec.split(",")(4).toDouble, rec )).sortByKey(false).map(_._2)
```

Here we can use saveAsTextFile API, But it's an action while we need to limit rows through transformations.

Comment: I'm suspecting, that this has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34206508/is-there-a-way-to-take-the-first-1000-rows-of-a-spark-dataframe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to take the first 1000 rows of a Spark Dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34206508/is-there-a-way-to-take-the-first-1000-rows-of-a-spark-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `limit`  function to get selected n first rows

```
def limit(n: Int): Dataset[T]
```

> Returns a new Dataset by taking the first n rows. The difference
>   between this function and head is that head is an action and returns
>   an array (by triggering query execution) while limit returns a new
>   Dataset.

```
yourDF.limit(5)  // takes the first 5 rows
```

If you want to take first 5 rows as an array then you can use `take` function

```
yourDF.take(5)
```

Hope this helps!